# Splitting values into 2 different columns

Tags: excel, split

I am working on a data which has 2 different types of IDs: QuestionID and AnswerID. For a particular row, there more than one QuestionID and AnswerID. But, the IDs are grouped in brackets and separated commas. I have to make 2 columns: QuestionID column and AnswerID column where, the respective IDs have to be shown by line-break for each row. I have added images for reference. One image shows the original data and another image shows the format I want to show where QuestionID and ANswerID columns are visible. I have tried everything that I know but just am not able to get the result. Would appreciate any help be it using Excel or Python.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al8aZ.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By8fo.png)

Comment: Is necessary to declare your XL version, because is possible, but depends to funtions you have. Otherwise need VBA.
Can you share simple sheet of data?

Comment: "*I have tried everything that I know*". What have you tried and what didn't work. The screenshot looks like a JSON document, so possibly one of the Json parsers would be a way to go.  Did you try that or not?  If you did, what was the outcome?